# Why is an isometry satisfying $(f(x)+f(y))/2 = f((x+y)/2)$ an affine function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have some difficulty following a proof from *Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis Vol. 1* by Benyamini and Lindenstrauss. If I understand correctly, the authors claim that if an isometry between two balls in Banach spaces satisfies
$$\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} = f \left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right),$$
then it is affine. How can one obtain the characterizing analogous equation for arbitrary linear combinations from this?

This argument appears on p. 341 in the proof of Theorem 14.1, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doJoU.jpg) is a screenshot (the statement is the very last sentence).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Use induction to show that $f(ax+(1-a)y)=af(x)+(1-a)f(y)$ whenever $a$ is a dyadic rational.

Comment: Isn't it Jensen's Functional Equation?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, of course, or even faster: f as defined above is both convex and concave...

Comment: @RalphClausen I did not know about this functional equation before but yes, it is. Searching for it here on stackexchange also yields a ton of proofs (some of which have to be straightforwardly adapted because of the general setting).